# Replace image in another div with text upon mouse over elsewhere

Tags: javascript, mouseover

I have tried around a dozen different ways to do this, I'm only going to post my most recent attempts though.

Basically I am trying to have it so that when a user hovers the mouse over an image on the page, another image in a separate div gets replaced with text.

I have the JS variables for the text elements to replace as well as the original image being replaced to put it back.

My most recent attempts were:

```
function replaceMainPage(x) {
$('#logozone').empty();
$('#logozone').append(x);
}

function hoverCircles(y) {
$(this).hover(replaceMainPage(y), replaceMainPage(mainLogo));
}
```

I don't really understand the "this" feature of JS, but have also tried that function as:

```
function hoverCircles(y) {
$('#logozone').hover(replaceMainPage(y), replaceMainPage(mainLogo));
}
```

From here I have tried calling the function is my main JS file like so:

```
$("#cir1").hover(replaceMainPage(logoReplacements.cakes), replaceMainPage(mainLogo));
```

As well as tried doing it in html on the img element itself with a onmouseover. Nothing has worked yet.

Am also open to non-JS ways of handling this, but I looked for those as well and couldn't find anything.

Comment: could you make a fiddle?

Comment: **this** is a pointer to the current Object the function is connected to (e.g. `<button onclick="alert(this.innerHTML)">ButtonText</button>` will show a popup with `ButtonText` because this is the innerHTML of the element connected to the function `onclick`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will help you, here is a **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/23vw58tL/1/)**:

```
var oldContent = '';
$('.hoverMe').hover(function() {
    oldContent = $('.toReplace').html();
    $('.toReplace').html('xxxxxxxx');
}, function() {
    $('.toReplace').html(oldContent);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="hoverMe">
    HOVER ME
</div>
<div class="toReplace">
    <img src="//cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/360031/hubfs/feature_practicetest.jpg?t=1470774914678&width=365">
</div>
```

I've created a global variable called `oldContent`. When `hover` on the `.hoverMe` div, store the old content of that div, change the content of div, and when you move your mouse out, put back the old content.

**UPDATE**

Based on OP comment, I create another [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/23vw58tL/2/) where you can set any text on the `.hoverMe`

If there are longer texts, or kind of texts what can not be stored in the data attribute, then add `data-id="1"` to `n`, and retreive the text through ajax based on the id.

Comment: This seems to work great. Anyway to do it for 8 images each needing a different 'xxxxxxxx' without having to have this in there 8 times .hoverMe1 2 3 etc? I already have a variable setup with all the possibilities like textReplace.example1 textReplace.example2 textReplace.example3 etc

Comment: Is these are simple short text, or it could be longer, or contain html tags?

Comment: It's short things like <h3>Cakes</h3> Longest one would be <h3>Special Occassions</h3>

Comment: @SteveMedley Check my updated answer. If it works for you, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="firstImgDiv">
  <div class="text"></div>
  <img src="a.png" onmouseenter="replaceImg('secondImgDiv', 'new Text')">
</div>
<div id="secondImgDiv">
  <div class="text"></div>
  <img src="b.png" onmouseenter="replaceImg('firstImgDiv', 'new Text')">
</div>
```

JS

```
function replaceImg(id, text){
  // show all images again
  $('img').show();
  // clear all text
  $('.text').html('');
  // hide target img
  $('#'+id+' > img').hide();
  // set target text
  $('#'+id+' > .text').html(text);
}
```